# Google hangout in gmail : How to display textual notification?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, gmail, notifications

I have got a problem :
With the first google chat integrated in gmail, I can see when people talk to me on top right of my screen.

I switched to new hangout chat:
How to display textual notification instead of sound notification when a conversation start ? (like when a email is received).

I read google doc without success to find answer....

I run latest chrome on mac 10.7

Should I go to adium + growl notification ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

To people who as same problem:

I ended by using Adium + Growl, because it was very important to me.